# How to speed up redrawing of background image in CFormView

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a single document template application. Main view inherits `CFormView` which draws png image on background. Also, I want to place `CDialog`-based object into this `CFormView`. This object, `Fragment`, has a `CStatic` control which text I want to update. This controls' background is made transparent. I have found that in case of backgound image in `CFormView` the text on `Fragment`'s control overlays itself on update. I tried to invalidate corresponding area on both `CStatic` and `Fragment`, but that doesn't help - it looks like text is drawn on parent's background. So, I started to invalidate `CFormView`'s region.

It helps, but there is a problem that on text update `CStatic` blinks like it (or its background) is drawing with a lag (or too slow), and I want to avoid this blinking. (I tried to record gif, but blinking is not visible on it.)

Here is the code:

`fragment.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "Fragment.h"
#include "resource.h"

class Fragment : public CDialog
{
public:
    Fragment(CWnd* pParent = nullptr) : CDialog(IDD_FRAGMENT1, pParent) {}

    HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
    void   OnBnClickedButton1();

#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum
    {
        IDD = IDD_FRAGMENT1
    };
#endif

protected:
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(Fragment)
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);

    CStatic m_label;
};
```

`fragment.cpp`:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Fragment.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(Fragment, CDialog)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Fragment, CDialog)
ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &Fragment::OnBnClickedButton1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void Fragment::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LABEL, m_label);
}

void Fragment::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        CString text;
        text.Format(L"Hello, static - %d%%", i);
        m_label.SetWindowText(text);
        CRect rect;
        m_label.GetWindowRect(&rect);
        GetParent()->ScreenToClient(&rect);
        GetParent()->InvalidateRect(&rect);
        GetParent()->UpdateWindow();
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

HBRUSH Fragment::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
}
```

'MainView.h':

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

class Fragment;
class MainView : public CFormView
{
public:
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum{ IDD = IDD_TRANSPARENTDIALOG_FORM };
#endif
    
    MainDoc* GetDocument() const;
    virtual BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
protected:
    MainView() noexcept;
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(MainView)
    void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
    void OnInitialUpdate();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    Fragment* fragment = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::Image> m_backgroundImage = nullptr;

    BOOL MainView::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* dc);
};
```

'MainView.cpp':

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "Fragment.h"
#include "TransparentDialog.h"
#include "MainDoc.h"
#include "MainView.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(MainView, CFormView)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MainView, CFormView)
ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

Gdiplus::Image* LoadImageFromMemory(uint8_t* data, ULONG size)
{
    IStream* memoryStream       = nullptr;
    ULONG    writen             = 0;
    auto     createStreamResult = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &memoryStream);
    if (createStreamResult != S_OK) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    HRESULT hr = memoryStream->Write(data, size, &writen);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        memoryStream->Release();
        return nullptr;
    }

    auto image = new Gdiplus::Image(memoryStream);
    memoryStream->Release();
    return image;
}

Gdiplus::Image* LoadPngFromResources(UINT resourceId)
{
    Gdiplus::Image* image          = nullptr;
    HRSRC           resourceHandle = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resourceId), L"PNG");
    if (resourceHandle) {
        HGLOBAL resource = LoadResource(NULL, resourceHandle);
        if (resource) {
            uint8_t* resourceData = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(LockResource(resource));
            if (resourceData) {
                image = LoadImageFromMemory(resourceData, SizeofResource(NULL, resourceHandle));
            }
        }
    }
    return image;
}

MainView::MainView() noexcept
    : CFormView(IDD_TRANSPARENTDIALOG_FORM)
{
    m_backgroundImage = std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::Image>(LoadPngFromResources(IDB_PNG1));
}

void MainView::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CFormView::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BOOL MainView::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    return CFormView::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}

void MainView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CFormView::OnInitialUpdate();
    GetParentFrame()->RecalcLayout();
    ResizeParentToFit();

    fragment = new Fragment(this);
    fragment->Create(IDD_FRAGMENT1, this);
    fragment->ShowWindow(true);
}

BOOL MainView::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* dc)
{
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(dc->m_hDC);
    graphics.DrawImage(
        m_backgroundImage.get(), 0, 0, m_backgroundImage.get()->GetWidth(), m_backgroundImage.get()->GetHeight());

    return true;
}

MainDoc* MainView::GetDocument() const
{
    return (MainDoc*)m_pDocument;
}
```

Note: updating text on button click 10 times with sleeping in between is just for testing purpuses. After removing `Sleep` and setting to update text only once per button click, the flickering will persist anyway.

Also, I've found that updating text is irrelevant here, the flickering persist even when just updating parent window using the following code:

```
void Fragment::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CRect rect;
    m_label.GetWindowRect(&rect);
    GetParent()->ScreenToClient(&rect);
    GetParent()->InvalidateRect(&rect);
    GetParent()->UpdateWindow();
}
```

Comment: Message handlers are called synchronously. When you put `Sleep(1000);` in a message handler that window is now unresponsive for a second. Run it in a loop 10 times and the window is unresponsive for 10 seconds. Don't `Sleep()` in a message handler.

Comment: It's just for testing purpuses. If I remove `Sleep` and update text only once per button click the flickering persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some few questions:

1. Why do you create a child dialog? `CFormView` is a dialog-resource-based view, so you can place controls directly on it.
2. Why are you using GDI+? Only because you want to use a PNG image? If the PNG just covers the form's background, and you are not concerned about alpha transparency or sth (what is "under" the "background" image anyway, I think nothing), there are alternative solutions, like using the Windows Imaging component or MFC's `CImage` class. Or even consider using an different format for your image resource - it's an embedded resource, not an external file that can be changed dynamically, so I think this would be acceptable.
3. Why are you using `OnEraseBkgnd()` instead of `OnPaint()`? It works much beter - and if it always paints the same image it doesn't "flicker", just fills the invalid part.

It think that the problem is that you are performing a full invalidate-update cycle (and this involves GDI+ calls too) only for updating a small area on your form. My suggestion is:

- Remove the whole `Fragment` class and place the button and the label directly on the form-view's dialog resource. Otherwise set the "Control" property for `Fragment`, in addition to "Child".
- Do not use `OnEraseBkgnd()`, use `OnPaint()` instead.
- As said above, try avoiding GDI+, instead use a DDB image and better modify it as needed (eg resize, crop, tile etc) during initialization (you may have to do this when the view is resized too), so that the bitmap can be drawn using `BitBlt()` (1:1 transfer), which is very fast.

But still, invalidating and repainting the whole parent window only for updating the (overlaid) static text control is an overkill. A good alternative is do not invalidate, instead draw only the area occupied by the static control. This can be done by calling `GetDC()`/`ReleaseDC()`, which updates an area immediately (synchronously), and not through the message-queue, as the invalidate-erase-repaint operation does - it can perform such "live" updates, even if the UI thread is busy. I'm talking about the `OnBnClickedButton1()` operation only, you will still have to respond to `OnEraseBkgnd()` or `OnPaint()` for "normal" invalidation/repainting (eg when the window is minimized, maximized, restored, uncovered etc). Read this documentation for better insight: [Painting and Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/painting-and-drawing).

You may also find the link below interesting (hope it doesn't confuse you instead):
[How can I use WS_CLIP­CHILDREN and still be able to draw a control with a transparent background?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20181005-00/?p=99905)

Comment: Thanks, I will try all of your suggestions. And responding to your questions: 1) It was spontaneous and seems to be easy decision, only few weeks after project start I asked myself the same question), I will reconsider this approach; 2) Yes, because of PNG and because I already has a code for loading PNG from resources, I also has a control-wrapper around `Gdiplus Image`, so I'm just using it; 3) `OnEraseBackground` is often recommended to deal with background, so I'm just embraced it as option of the first choice.

Comment: Also, just tonight I realized that `CDC` parameter of `OnEraseBkgnd` contains a `ClipBox` parameter which, I beleive, contains invalidated `RECT`, so I can paint only this smaller area. It looks, it is working for my test app, but for main app I often receive large area. I don't understand why yet.

Comment: @qloq Clipping prevents rendering outside a window's area. The clip box is a rectangular bounding box around the clipping area. It is not the same thing as the invalidated region. You can get the invalidated rectangle from a [`CPaintDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cpaintdc-class)'s `m_ps` member.